# Downcast list return type in overriden getter of child class

Tags: java, downcast

I have the following class hierarchy:

```java
public class U {};
public class IU extends U {};

public class A {
    private final List<? extends U> us;

    public A(Collection<? extends U> us) { 
        this.us = new ArrayList<>(us);
    }

    public List<? extends U> getUs() { return this.us; }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(Collection<IU> ius) { super(ius); }

    @Override
    public List<IU> getUs() { return (List<IU>) super.getUs(); }
}
```

The `A.us` list will never be modified so by construction, I know that `getUs()` from `A` will return a `List` containing only `IU` when called from an object of type `B` (unless someone does some really messy stuff, which I don't really bother with here).

The cast in `B.getUs` is marked as unsafe,  so my questions are:

- Is this cast actually safe or is there some issues I did not see?
- If so, how can I mark it as such to remove the warning?

Comment: "I know that `getUs()` from `A` will return a `List` containing only `IU` when called from an object of type `B`" Well if _you_ know that, then the cast is safe. You can suppress the warning if you like. The warning is just there to warn you that Java won't check the cast for you, so you should check it yourself, in some way.

Comment: From the perspective of `B`, there's just the risk that `A` might change and make `us` mutable, but perhaps you include that in that "messy stuff". Beside that, I'm of the opinion that returning a type parameterized with a wildcard isn't very good practice. You can skip the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method.

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks. Maybe you're right and I've gone in the wrong direction with my design, I will think about it.

Comment: @ernest_k I split `U` into `IU` and `OU` to get better type safety in some places, but then I made a lot of changes and what I was doing was to allow for something generic and allow for both `IU` and `OU` everywhere, which actually makes no sense since I can simply remove `IU` and `OU` and use `U`... Your comment made me realize that, thanks.

Comment: Well, just in the interest of mentioning the option, the code in your post can be made more type-safe by making `A` generic: `public class A<T extends U>` (with `us` being declared as `private final List<T> us;`). With that, `B` would `extends A<IU>`, which would remove the need to cast anywhere. Now, the question is whether your design with `A` non-generic was intentional...? I believe that both Sweeper and I assumed you didn't want to make `A` generic.

Comment: @ernest_k I did not want to make `A` generic because then I'd have to deal with `A<?>` everywhere or have to make everything generic... Note that this probably come from the bad design of `A` which I changed now, removing the purpose for this question. I think making `A` generic might also generate some issues with the overloading of some functions due to how Java handles generic types.

Comment: @Holt _"might also generate some issues"_ your `A` **is generic** but you are using a wildcard. For `B` the genericity (of `A`) is fixed to be `UI` (i.e. `B` is not generic) that's why you can write `class B extends A<IU>` and generics disappear for `B`. But `A` is generic and you should consider him as such (downcast is as `class B extends A<IU>` but in runtime instead compilation time). Come on, that downcast is incorrect (imho).

Answer (score 1):

Since `A` is a type container, the contained type should be explicit for every `A` (final) definition.

Then, simply change:

```
public class U {};
public class IU extends U {};

public class A<T extends U> {
    private final List<T> us;

    public A(Collection<T> us) {
        this.us = new ArrayList<>(us);
    }

    public List<T> getUs() { return this.us; }
}

public class B extends A<IU> {
    public B(Collection<IU> ius) { super(ius); }

    @Override
    public List<IU> getUs() { return super.getUs(); }
}
```

now, `A` works for every type you want and the correct type **is enforced at compile time** (without warnings).